# Detect if image is visible on background

Tags: android, image, colors

I have a dialog and show icons of icon packs in it. Depending on my apps theme and the icon color I want to dynamically decide, if I need to show the icon on a background or without (depending on if the icon is visible on the dialog background or not).

This means:

- showing a white icon on a black background => fine, no icon background is needed
- shwoing a white icon with black border on a white background => fine, no icon background needed
- showing white icon on a white background => problem, I need to add a background behind the icon so that the user can see the icon

Any ideas how to do this? Efficiently as this will be done for each icon in a dialog...

Or any alternative ideas to solve the problem?

**Problem to solve**

*Compare dialog background with a color calculated from the icon => if the differ enough, don't draw a background behind the icon, if not, draw a background that differs enough from the icon*

How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a generic function which shows a dialog. In the parameters of the function you can pass the context, image and the background color itself. Make it as a singleton and call it from where you want to show the dialog. Calling a function would be easy.I am attaching a dialog with listener.

```
 public void showErrorDialogWithListener(Activity activity, String message, final View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    try {
        try {
            if (errorDialog != null && errorDialog.isShowing()) {
                errorDialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        errorDialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.DialogTheme);
        errorDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        errorDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.Animations_LoadingDialogFade;
        errorDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_error);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = errorDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        errorDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        layoutParams.dimAmount = Constants.dialogDimAmount;
        errorDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        errorDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        errorDialog.setCancelable(true);
        errorDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        LinearLayout mParentRl = (LinearLayout) errorDialog.findViewById(R.id.parentRl);
        BaseActivity.overrideFonts(activity, mParentRl);
        Button mBtnOk = (Button) errorDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        TextView messageTv = (TextView) errorDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageTv);
        messageTv.setText(message);
        mBtnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickListener.onClick(view);
                errorDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        errorDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a dialog with just one button. Hope this helps.